# Angular CLI overrides ubuntu newgrp command

Tags: angular, ubuntu

I want to use a newgrp command,

```
newgrp docker
```

But I got below error,

```
The specified command ("completion") is invalid. For a list of available options,
run "ng help".
```

[image]

Is it possible to use newgrp with Angluar cli installed ?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu with Angular CLI installed and don't seem to have this issue.  What happens if you run `/usr/bin/newgrp docker`?

Comment: @JasonWhite Same result